# Number of Times Other Apps Opened iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I want to check how many times app is opened in iPhone 
e.g

Number of times you opened instagram

Number of times you opened Facebook

Number of times you opened whatsapp

How can i achieve the same in ios

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to monitor other apps/user activity from your application. So you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't.**  The reason is they are **Sandboxed**.

-